# postgresql full text search rails title and description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am trying to search a model with title and description, but having the following error. I want to be able to search title and description and the type of job. Any help will be really appreciated.

> PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of OR must be type boolean, not
>   type character varying LINE 1: ...T  "refinery_jobs".* FROM
>   "refinery_jobs"  WHERE (title OR d...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT  "refinery_jobs".* FROM "refinery_jobs"  WHERE (title OR
>   description LIKE '%consultant%' AND job_type LIKE '%Contract%') LIMIT
>   10

**Here is my query**

```
results << model.limit(RESULTS_LIMIT).where("title OR description LIKE ? AND job_type LIKE ?","%#{query}%","%#{job_type}%")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error says that postgresql expects both side of an `OR` to evaluate to a truthy value.  in your sql, this error pertains to the left side of `OR` which is simply `title`.  just change your query to

```
where(
  "(title LIKE :query OR description LIKE :query) AND job_type LIKE :job_type",
  query: "%#{query}%",
  job_type: "%#{job_type}%"
)
```

Comment: Thanks jvnill, that sorted my issue :-)